# Send gzip to another server that uses onKeyboardInteractive with node-ssh

Tags: ssh

I am using node-ssh (in a firebase cloud function) to create an archive of a folder on one server and I want to send this archive to another server that is using keyboard interactive auth but I don't know how to manage this.

**What I tried** :

- Using SSH **scp** command like so : `scp -r my_backup.gz username@server-2.com:/backups-test/`while being connected to the first server
  => But I guess (and hope) that the second server needs its password to accept the operation, and I don't know how to manage this as easily as I did with my first server with node-ssh (using tryKeyboard and onKeyboardInteractive)
- Use **async / await** to first connect to the first server and then send the archive to the second server but everything I am referencing to in the `then()` of the second server's connection, belongs to the second server so I cannot ask to transfer the archive from the first server to the second one.

**My code** :
before implementing the connection to the second server :

```
var password = '***'
ssh.connect({
    host: '***',
    username: '***',
    port: 22,
    password,
    tryKeyboard: true,
    onKeyboardInteractive: (name, instructions, instructionsLang, prompts, finish) => {
        if (prompts.length > 0 && prompts[0].prompt.toLowerCase().includes('password')) {
            finish([password])
        }
    }
}).then((value) => {
    await ssh.execCommand('touch my_backup.gz', {
        cwd: '/home/directoryName'
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log('TOUCH OK');
        if (result.stderr != '') console.log('TOUCH STDERR: ' + result.stderr);
    }).catch((error) => {
        ssh.dispose();
        return response.status(401).send('error : ' + error);
    });

    await ssh.execCommand('tar --exclude=my_backup.gz -zcvf my_backup.gz .', {
        cwd: '/home/directoryName'
    }).then((result) => {
        console.log('ARCHIVE CREATED !');
        if (result.stderr != '') console.log('STDERR: ' + result.stderr);
    }).catch((error) => {
        ssh.dispose();
        return response.status(401).send('error : ' + error);
    });


    ssh.dispose();
    return response.status(200).send('ARCHIVE CREATED');

}).catch((error) => {
    ssh.dispose();
    return response.status(401).send('connection error : ' + error);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the FTP protocol via wget, simplifying the process.